# Filter on multiple variables, nyc flights

Tags: r, dataframe

Having trouble with solving the following question working with the flights dataframe in R:

"To how many destinations did flights depart only in January 2013?"

Comment: Waht you want to do is to filter on certain rows. You can use `filter` from package `dplyr` for that. Apart from that please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow:

1. Before asking a question please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
2. Please show some efforts how and what you have tried.

Here is how you can solve your task: First filter for year and month, then select the distinct destinations then use `summarise`:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)
flights %>% 
  filter(year==2013 & month == 1) %>% 
  distinct(dest) %>% 
  summarise(n())
```